# Get item from dynamodb table using separate index table with Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, iot

I am creating a weather station using the [Particle Electron](https://www.particle.io/cellular) and AWS. I have managed to get the returned data sent to a DynamoDB table "weather" which contains all of the weather data with the following schema (with included sample values):

```
Item{13}
deviceId: 540056000a51343334363138 (String) (Primary Partition Key)
tm: 1458754711 (Number) (Primary Sort Key) 
batSoC: 89 (String)
batV: 4.01 (String)
hum: 27.9 (String)
lat: 41.2083 (String)
lon: -73.3439 (String)
pres: 968.4 (String)
temp: 19.8 (String)
uvI: 0.1 (String)
wDir: 0 (String)
wGst: 0.0 (String)
wSpd: 0.0 (String)
```

as well as a separate "weather_index" table which contains only the `deviceId` and `tm` attributes for the most recent data that was written to the main table (kind of like an atomic counter but for a periodically updated unix timestamp value). So if the "weather_index" item above was the most recent entry, the item in the "weather_index" table would look like this:

```
Item{2}
deviceIdString: 540056000a51343334363138 (String) (Primary Partition Key)
tmNumber: 1458754711 (Number)
```

I am currently trying to write a very basic web frontend in Node.js (which, prior to this project, I have had no experience with, so I am still learning) and can't figure out how to:

1. Perform a DynamoDB getItem which contains a parameter retrieved via a previous getItem. Like:

latestTime = getItem(weather_index, deviceId) // Gets the time "tm" of the most recent weather observation and stores it in "latestTime"
// Where "weather_index" is the table name

currentWeather = getItem(deviceId, tm) // Gets the weather observation for the specified "tm" value and stores it in "currentWeather"
//  Where "tm" is the unix time-stamp of the most recent observation

I then want to be able to print the individual values to the terminal/webpage/carrier pigeon/etc... (Something along the lines of `currentWeather.deviceId`, `currentWeather.tm`, `currentWeather.batSoC`, etc...

I have the following code that I can't really make work properly:

```
/*
 * Module dependencies
 */
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')

// weathermon_dev credentials
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'REDACTED for obvious reasons', secretAccessKey: 'This bit too'});

// Select AWS region
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

var db = new AWS.DynamoDB();
// db.listTables(function(err,data) {
//   console.log(data.TableNames);
// });


var time = Date.now() / 1000;
time = Math.round(time);
//console.log("Time: ");
//console.log(time);

time = Math.round(time);



var deviceId = "540056000a51343334363138"

var params = {
  Key: {
    deviceId: {S: deviceId}
  },
  TableName: 'weather_index'
};

var timeJson;

db.getItem(params, function(err,data) {
  if (err) console.log(err); // an error occurred
  else console.log(data); // successful response
    var timeJson = JSON.parse(data);
})

// var timeJson = JSON.parse(data);
// var itemTime = timeJson.item;

console.log("timeJSON: " + timeJson);

// console.log("itemTime: " + itemTime);



var params = {
  Key: {
    deviceId: {S: deviceId},
    time: {N: 'tm'}
  },
  TableName: 'weather'
};


db.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err); // an error occurred
  else console.log(data); // successful response
})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into how NodeJS asynchronous calls work. You would need to wait until the callback from the first `getItem()` is called before you perform the second `getItem()`.

I've rewritten the relevant part of your code here, to show you what I'm talking about, but I recommend you try to understand why the code needs to be written in this way instead of just copy/pasting it.

```
var deviceId = "540056000a51343334363138"

var params = {
  Key: {
    deviceId: {S: deviceId}
  },
  TableName: 'weather_index'
};

var timeJson;

db.getItem(params, function(err,data) {
  if (err) console.log(err); // an error occurred
  else {
    console.log(data); // successful response
    var timeJson = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log("timeJSON: " + timeJson);

    // Inside this callback we have the weather_index tm value, 
    // so query the weather table here.
    var params = {
      Key: {
        deviceId: {S: deviceId},
        time: {N: 'tm'}
      },
      TableName: 'weather'
    };

    db.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err); // an error occurred
      else {
        console.log(data); // successful response
        // TODO: Use the database response data here
      }
    });
  }
});
```